# how to get HTML value in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

i want to get value in php

here is my code:

PHP:

```
<php $hddInput = $_POST['hddInput']; ?>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="hddInput" id="hddInput" value="test" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>

name: <?php echo $hddInput; ?>
```

it works now when i click on submit button and the Value shows in PHP

but how i can show value without clicking on submit?

Comment: Have you tryed parsing user.id into some hidden `<input>` and gettin a copy, like `$userId`, using this latter, instead?

Comment: I don't that's even possible. If you tried to include a PHP string into Javascript or HTML, that would be possible. But the other way around, I don't think so.

Comment: i didn't try this.. can you give me a example? @lockedz

Comment: If I corretcly understood, you want to get the value into a PHP var, from a JavaScript var value, right? I'll post it has an answer, but don't know if it'll fit your needs. @AhsenMughal

Comment: yes... can you please post the answer!

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, you concatenate strings using `.`, not `+`.

```
if (! copy('http://graph.facebook.com/'
    . $userId 
    . '/picture?width=100&height=100', //....
```

You need to get the `$userId` into PHP, either using `$_GET` superglobal or one of 100000 other ways.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you append a

```
<input type="hidden" name="hddInput" id="hddInput" value="" />
```

Then, with **JS**, get the `user.id` value to this

```
document.getElementById("hddInput").value = user.id;
```

In the **PHP**, you could retrieve the value by simply asking the `$hddInput` through `$_GET/$_POST['hddInput'];`

Comment: Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): 'http://graph.facebook.com//picture?width=100&height=100' is not a valid JPEG file in /home3/xxxxx/public_html/apps/index.php on line 76

Comment: there should be user.id after .com/ /.. , but nothing shows

Comment: Are you usign a get or post in your form? Getting the value through $_GET['hddInput']; ? (add a name="hddInput") to the input too! I'll edit this.

Comment: let my edit my Question with example code... Please check